# Django. How parse xml file during upload

Tags: xml, django, xml-parsing, django-forms, django-views

my Views

```py
class TestFilesView(FormView):
    form_class = TestFilesForm
    template_name = 'testy/xml_files_upload.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                instance = TestFiles(
                    id_test=TestHeader(self.kwargs['id']),
                    name='xx',
                    file_name=f.name,
                    file_field=f
                )
                instance.save()

            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('tests_list')
```

How i can open uploading xml file, get "name" atribute from xml file and forward it to my istance name variable ?

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a parsing library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You can try something like below:

```
if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                instance = TestFiles(
                    id_test=TestHeader(self.kwargs['id']),
                    name='xx',
                    file_name=f.name,
                    file_field=f
                )
                instance.save()
                with open(f.read(), 'r') as file:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml.parser')
                    instance.name = soup.name
                    instance.save()
```

Comment: when i use your solituon i getting error : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Allright, my mistake, just replace `with open(f, 'r') as file:` by `with open(f.read(), 'r') as file:`
However you may have some issue with the open function (not suited for xml). If so, remove it and just try `soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'xml.parser')`

Comment: However, from the django documentation, take care to your you file size. 


UploadedFile.read()¶

    Read the entire uploaded data from the file. Be careful with this method: if the uploaded file is huge it can overwhelm your system if you try to read it into memory. You’ll probably want to use chunks() instead; see below.

UploadedFile.multiple_chunks(chunk_size=None)¶

    Returns True if the uploaded file is big enough to require reading in multiple chunks. By default this will be any file larger than 2.5 megabytes, but that’s configurable; see below.